Tracing Parameter Provenance with CodeQL in VSCode Codebase
I'm exploring the capabilities of CodeQL for tracking the provenance of parameters in large codebases, specifically focusing on the positionDelta parameter within the Visual Studio Code (VSCode) repository. My goal is to understand how effectively CodeQL can trace this parameter back to its origin across multiple files and functions.
In the VSCode codebase, the parameter positionDelta is used in vscode/src/vs/editor/browser/widget/codeEditor/codeEditorWidget.ts line 1778 as follows:
compositionType: (text: string, replacePrevCharCnt: number, replaceNextCharCnt: number, positionDelta: number) => {
    if (replaceNextCharCnt || positionDelta) {
        ...
    }
    ...
}

By manually following references and definitions, I traced the usage of positionDelta through several files, such as viewController.ts and textAreaHandler.ts, eventually reaching textAreaInput.ts where it's part of an event firing method:
this._register(this._textArea.onCompositionUpdate((e) => {
    ...
    this._onType.fire(typeInput);
    ...
}

Given this chain of usages, I'm curious whether CodeQL can automatically trace the positionDelta parameter from its usage in codeEditorWidget.ts to its origin and through all the intermediate steps. How deep can CodeQL go in uncovering the flow of this parameter in a complex codebase like VS Code's? Can it connect all the dots as I did manually?
I tried the following query:
import javascript

class PositionDeltaFlowConfig extends DataFlow::Configuration {
  PositionDeltaFlowConfig() { this = "PositionDeltaFlowConfig" }

  override predicate isSource(DataFlow::Node source) { any() }

  override predicate isSink(DataFlow::Node sink) {
    exists(Expr expr, Function f |
      f.getName() = "compositionType" and
      f.getFile().getBaseName() = "codeEditorWidget.ts" and
      expr = f.getBody().getAChild*().(Expr) and
      expr.toString() = "positionDelta" and
      sink = DataFlow::exprNode(expr) and
      sink.getStartLine() = 1753
    )
  }
}

from PositionDeltaFlowConfig config, DataFlow::Node source, DataFlow::Node sink
where config.hasFlow(source, sink)
select source, source.getFile().getAbsolutePath() + " in line: " + source.getStartLine(), sink,
  sink.getFile().getAbsolutePath() + " in line: " + sink.getStartLine()

With this query, I can successfully get the line of compositionType in vscode/src/vs/editor/browser/widget/codeEditor/codeEditorWidget.ts line 1778. From here, I can keep tracking of compositionType:
import javascript

predicate isCompositionTypeFunction(Function f) {
  f.getName() = "compositionType" and
  f.getNumParameter() = 4 and
  f.getParameter(0).getName() = "text" and
  f.getParameter(1).getName() = "replacePrevCharCnt" and
  f.getParameter(2).getName() = "replaceNextCharCnt" and
  f.getParameter(3).getName() = "positionDelta"
}

from Function f
where isCompositionTypeFunction(f)
select f

But it can not find the instances like this._viewController.compositionType(e.text, e.replacePrevCharCnt, e.replaceNextCharCnt, e.positionDelta);
